# All Javascript Commands for URL's

Tags: javascript, url, command

So I want a list of all javascript commands what can manipulate or get information about URL's.

Example:

```
window.location.href
```

Comment: What are we? An encyclopedia? A programmer's reference?

Comment: Can you provide any more detail than this? What exactly with URLs are you trying to do something about? Do you want to manipulate the browser window URL or also anchor tags and the like?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

Comment: No! Nobody is saying that you need to answer, if you know just one about them, or you know a useful link that's good too :)

Comment: `for (var prop in window.location) { console.log(prop, window.location[prop]); }`

Comment: `window.location.href` is not a "Javascript command".  Then again, I'm not sure of *anything* that I'd call a "command" in Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To list the properties of an object you can use this method:

```
var p = [];

for (var i in window.location)
{
    p.push(i);
}

alert(p.join("\n"));
```

For `window.location` I get:

- href
- protocol
- search
- hash
- pathname
- hostname
- host
- port
- reload
- replace
- assign

Answer (score 2):

[W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/Window/#navigation)
[W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp)
[Mozilla](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)

Comment: That's a link to W3 Schools, not to W3C.

Comment: you are correct? - i added w3c to reduce confusion

Comment: W3 just means world wide web.  It's incorrect to think that W3 always means W3C.  W3Schools is, in may ways, more popular than W3C.  Without talking about the W3C anywhere, you cannot think that W3 refers to the  consortium.  At the same time, you can't think it refers to w3schools either.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not really clear. However, I suggest that you have a look one the [Javascript reference from Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference). The response to your question is here, no doubt about that!

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location